# How to add automatically append ,00 when user is entering a value inside TextBox?

Tags: c#, .net

I have some textboxes in my form where the user need to enter the different prices of article, what I want to do is to automatically add `,00` whenever text is changed . So when the user types `123` it is displayed like `123,00` !

I tried with code below but it doesn't seem to work :

```
private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!textBox6.Text.Contains(","))

        textBox6.SelectionStart =textBox6.TextLength;
        textBox6.Text += ",00";
    }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Assuming Windows Forms, take a look at the [MaskedTextBox Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx)

Comment: No one uses MaskedTextBox because it's so ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the code with  keypress event of the TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.EndsWtih` to check the end of the string only.

```
private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!textBox6.Text.EndsWith(",00"))
        textBox6.Text += ",00"
}
```

Rather than the `TextChanged` event, use the `Leave` event unless you really need the change to happen instantly. Doing complex manipulation like this every time a key is pressed tends to not work well.

Comment: And what happens when the user enters "123,0"?

Comment: @Metro Obviously you need to handle that case too, but it's not terribly difficult to do. Consider it an exercise left to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
textBox6.BeginInvoke(delegate ()=> 
{
   textBox6.Text +=",00"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Jason has said, you could use the `leave` event, if this is unsuitable, then convert it to a string and feed it back into the textbox like so:

```
  private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string myString = textBox6.Text;
            if (!myString.Contains(','))
            {
                myString += ",00";
            }

            textBox6.Text = myString;
        }
```

**I would also advise looking into a check to make sure the users are only entering numeric values.**

Answer (score 0):

Try string.Format.

```
string numStr = textBox6.Text;
decimal num;

if(decimal.TryParse(numStr, out num)){
  textBox6.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", num);
}
```

However, you need to specify some cultures if you need comma ',' as the decimal separator.